# How do they come up with a freezing point of ~-60F for CaCl2 & H20?

Tags: phase

What am I missing?  I cannot reconcile the difference between what the internet says the freezing point of CaCl2 is vs the calculation, which means my calculation must be off, but I am not sure how.

Example Calculation:

- A Solute of 1700g of CaCl2 would equate to ~15.32 Moles @ 110.98 Atomic Mass.
- Mix in 1 Gallon of water, or 3.785 kg.
- This represents a ~31% solution (1700/(1700+3785))
- Molality would be 4.047 (15.32 / 3.875)
- With a Van't Hoff of 3...
- The Freezing Point Depression would be -22.52C (3*1.855*4.047)

I think all of that is right, but when I look at the tables online they show that a 31% CaCl2 solution would have a freezing point of ~-34C - ~-37C

- http://meltsnow.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/image006.png
- http://www.oxy.com/OurBusinesses/Chemicals/Products/Documents/CalciumChloride/173-01791.pdf

These sites shows a 30% concentration to have a freezing point of ~-46.1C:

- https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/calcium-chloride-water-d_1186.html
- http://www.tetrachemicalseurope.com/getFile.asp?File_Content_ID=1624
- https://www.dynalene.com/v/vspfiles/templates/210/datasheets/Dynalene_Calcium_Chloride_Series_Technical_Data_Sheet.pdf
- http://www.phasediagram.dk/binary/CaCl2.PNG

Answer (score 4):

They didn't come up with the number. They went out into the field and actually *measured* it. Chemistry is an experimental science, you know.

Your calculations are fine; it is just they were never *supposed to* work in the first place. When you calculate the freezing point depression like that, you use the **linear approximation**, and all approximations have their limits. You can't apply it to a concentrated solution; the error will be too great, just as you observed.

Look at them graphs by your links, they are pretty far from being linear; they are bent. (We may apply some hand-waving about molarity and molality not being the same thing, but it doesn't explain the effect away completely). Look at the left corner of the graph with a magnifying glass (related picture: [Why do increasing concentrations of zinc chloride not linearly decrease the freezing point?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/64493/why-do-increasing-concentrations-of-zinc-chloride-not-linearly-decrease-the-free/64498#64498)). What would you call that section of the curve? Almost linear, shall we say? Well, that's where our approximation is almost precise.

So it goes.