# Microfiltration for saturated solutions of highly hygroscopic compounds?

Tags: aqueous-solution, equipment, purification

Is it possible to pass saturated solutions of compounds with very high solubility through filters with small pores (e.g. passing a saturated aqueous ZnCl2 solution at 90C through a 2mcm glassfiber filter with the help of partial vacuum)?

Will it work well? Are there preferred methods for this? If not, is there any (reasonable) solution to filter out microparticles from such solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filtration is a mechanical operation.  Thus, if you have a *solution* of $\ce{ZnCl2}$, which (assuming you use water as solvent) dissociated into ions of $\ce{Zn^{2+}}$ and $\ce{Cl^-}$, a typical filter will not retain these ions.  Instead of using some vacuum (*potential* danger to evaporate some solvent, thus altering the concentration of he solution), you may consider filtration under pressure (e.g., across a [Schlenk fritt](https://www.chem.ucla.edu/%7Ebacher/CHEM174/glassware/Schlenkfilt.html) for larger scale, or a syringe filter at smaller scale [e.g., testing a spin coating]).

[image]

([credit](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/wha67841310?lang=en&region=US&cm_sp=Insite-_-caContent_prodMerch_gruCrossEntropy-_-prodMerch10-1))

If the solvent capacity for $\ce{ZnCl2}$ is not (this much) temperature dependent, you equally could perform the filtration near room temperature (e.g., $\pu{432.0 g}$ $\ce{ZnCl2}$ per $\pu{100 g}$ of water at $\pu{25 °C}$ listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinc_chloride)).

Comment: To be more precise: What I would like to do is to filter the saturated solution of highly hygroscopic compounds at a temperature at which as much as possible of the compound will cram into solution such as to maximize the common ion effect on crystalizing impurities in the solution (so in the case of ZnCl2 the idea would be to saturate it at 90C or so, then swirl slowly for a moment to allow for impurities to agglomerate into fewer/bigger crystals and then pass the solution through a 1-4mcm filter to, hopefully, get a solution of ZnCl2 of much higher purity on the other side of the filter).

Comment: I've never handled such highly saturated solutions so I'm not sure if visquosity or so would be a problem in passing them through a very small pore filter. One thing I had in mind was to be using some coarser sand above the filter such that larger impurity crystals don't get through to the small pore filter. One issue you mention is indeed that partial vacuum on the receiving side of the filter would risk clogging the filter by precipitation of the hygroscopic compound (by evaporating solvent).

Comment: Positive presssure is a possibility to explore (though I haven't thus far because my glassware won't hold much positive pressure at all). If I would have equipment able to hold say 2-3 atmospheres of positive pressure, do you think that would be enough (and that the pore size wouldn't be a problem if there's no vacuum on the receiving side of the filter)?

Comment: If the intend is to purify $\ce{ZnCl2}$, then -- beside the anticipated scale (g, kg, t) -- it must be clear in advance what the nagging impurities (and their concentration) currently are, and what (after purification) would be a level *good enough*. Otherwise the work will not find an end.  It could be that the undefined impurities are equally (or better) soluble in the solvent, too. Equally, filtration would proceed from coarse to fine filters just to prevent blockage, too.  A suitable pressure depends on the material, yet in addition e.g., shape and dimension of the container, too.

Comment: Small scale preparative column chromatography uses a gentle pressure (perhaps 1 bar) top push the eluent across the column, but column's preferred diameter is below 10 cm. What is the purpose of the ZnCl2 *after* purification? What did you find in Amareggo / Perrin «Purification of Laboratory Chemicals»? Given [this entry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/64493/why-do-increasing-concentrations-of-zinc-chloride-not-linearly-decrease-the-free) I would not wonder if it is some kind of sublimation instead of a (directed) crystallization. Of course one would start with a coarse filter.

Comment: There's about 150ppm of other metal ions in there. Probably lead, copper, cadmium, iron, silver, mercury, arsenic. Maybe also thallium, selenium, gallium, germanium, antimony, tin. If I could cut that down a lot by such a simple process as this it would be great. I think it could help with silver, lead and thallium more particularly.

Comment: (it's for perhaps 300g of ZnCl2)

Comment: I've read somewhere it could be purified by sublimation in a stream of HCl but given the BP of 732C I believe this must apply to minute amounts and there's no way I can put up a setup for this. Zinc as a metal has a fairly high vapor pressure as does HCl but there's nothing to say ZnCl2 would too and I couldn't find any data on the vapor pressure of ZnCl2. Also with such a high BP sublimation would inedvitably carry along some mercury and cadmium.

Comment: I've thought about recrystalizing in ethanol but (a) I don't have any reliable solubility data and I can't trust Wikipedia on the single data point it gives, (b) I'm afraid zinc ions would catalyze the formation of aldehydes in the alcohol.

Comment: If sublimation, or high vacuum distillation ([example](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11663-020-01876-y), seems easier to perform than for magnesium) is not an option (physics group in an university?), then this demanding specifications of purity are better delegated to chemical supplier selling the material with an certificate of analysis.  *E.g.*, [sigma](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/united-states.html) sells this with ≥99.995% purity  (#429430, max. 50.0 ppm trace metal), or at 99.999% purity (#229997, max 15 ppm trace metals). Crystallization *from solution* typically is not directed enough.

Comment: When you write "not directed enough" do you mean that it's not  directed at specific impurities? Would it be efficient at bringing the 150ppm trace metals down to say 5ppm trace metals after a few rounds?

Comment: "Directed" as in "zone melting" with a discrete layer of molten material passing the solid sample, e.g., to purify semiconducting metals in microelectronics ([open access example](https://doi.org/10.4236/jcpt.2018.81003)).  While a melting point of $\pu{290 °C}$ could be attained with some resistor wiring around an horizontal glass tube, I do not know if after hours of contact normal lab glass eventually would be eaten away from a melt of $\ce{ZnCl2}$ ...